# Lightbox Slideshow issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

This code is taken from W3schools.com. All I did was copy and paste an extra div box to create a new column. The problem is when I click on the 2nd row's image to enlarge it the code takes me back to 1st's 1st image. I am not sure what function is dealing with the whole clicking any image I want to enlarge it.

All I want is to be able to expand the rows with more pictures and then be able to click on any random and then the lightbox mode starts from the picture I clicked not the very first picture on the webpage.

The entire code can be found at : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_lightbox

```
       <h2 style="text-align:center">Sneek Peek</h2>

       <div class="row">
     <div class="column">
       <img src="img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" 
       class="hover-shadow cursor">
      </div>
         <div class="column">
      <img src="img_snow.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover- 
        shadow cursor">
         </div>
        <div class="column">
     <img src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" 
       class="hover- 
       shadow cursor">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
           <img src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" 
       class="hover- 
         shadow cursor">
      </div>

      <div class="column">
     <img src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover- 
   shadow cursor">
   </div>
 </div>

      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
     <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">

     <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">

     <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

     <div class="mySlides">

      <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="mySlides">

     <img src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
     <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

      <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
     </div>

      <div class="mySlides">

     <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>


   <div class="column">
   <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
   <img class="demo cursor" src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)">
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>

     <script>
        function openModal() {
    document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
  }

  function closeModal() {
     document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
  }

  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

 function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
 }

  function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
 }

 function showSlides(n) {
 var i;
 var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
 var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
 if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
 if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
 for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
 }
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
 dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when clicking the new 5th slide execute `onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)"`

In order to understand what happen when you click you need to go to the `script` part and understand what those two functions does.

Since you got it from w3schools, they put notes and explanation on their pages. So **first** thing i can recommend you is not using code unless you understand what it does, and **second** - w3schools not always accurate with their examples so it better that you vary your resources.

I advice MDN - they have really [good tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript).

Enjoy code!